# R - Trouble with space and '/' in variable and column name

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, rstudio

In my excel document I am using the column is "Mode of Communication" and within that column are entries that use either a space, "In Person," or a slash, "IM/Chat."

These keep throwing errors:

- Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'In.Person' not found
- Same for IM/Chat

I try using In.Person or IM.Chat but they raise errors. The code is:

```
png(filename="Number of Interactions by Communication Mode.png")
person <- subset(desktracker, Mode.of.Communication="")
ByChat <- ggplot(subset(desktracker, IM.Chat!=""), aes(x=IM.Chat)) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme_bw() +
  ylab("Number of Interactions") +
  xlab("By Chat") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "red"))
ByPerson <- ggplot(subset(person, In.Person =""), aes(x=In.Person)) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme_bw()+
  ylab("Number of Interactions") +
  xlab("In Person")
grid.arrange(ByChat, ByPerson, ByPhone, main="Number of Interactions by     Communication Mode
             for Reference 2016")
dev.off()
```

I am new to R and have taken up this project after someone left. So far I have tried changing the way I write "In Person" or "IM/Chat" in R to either "In.Person" or "IM.Chat" to different degrees without success. Maybe there is a wildcard I can use for IM/Chat to overcome the '/'? I tried changing the way it is presented in the excel sheet to "In_Person" and just "Chat" and that resulted in the same errors. I will keep messing around, but would welcome any suggestions. I will be sure to post a solution if I find one.

Thanks

Sorry, desktracker is the variable that I used to open the data set:

```
setwd("Z:/DesktrackR/Ref_Semester")
file = "Desk_Tracker_flat_8-17-15_through_5-9-16.csv"
desktracker <- read.csv(file, sep=",")
```

An idea of the content of the excel:

[image: Excel section for Chat]

[image: Column Names]

Comment: Without at least an idea about the content of desktracker, this is impossible to answer. Keep in mind that names of variables in a data frame should not contain spaces or special characters other than a dot if you want to avoid these problems.

Comment: Variable names that are not syntactically valid, such as ones with spaces or special symbols, can be used in ggplot2 via backticks, `.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your variable names, but I would suggest that if you do have headers you correct the column names of your data frame:

```
colnames(desktracker) <- gsub(" |/", '.', colnames(desktracker))
```

That will replace either space or / with a period, so you can access the variables easier.

Note: make sure you have `headers = TRUE` in `read.csv()`, as in:

```
setwd("Z:/DesktrackR/Ref_Semester")
file = "Desk_Tracker_flat_8-17-15_through_5-9-16.csv"
desktracker <- read.csv(file, sep=",", headers = TRUE)
```